# How to disable the keyboard shortcut "Enter" when reviewing?

Tags: anki

When reviewing when I press "Enter" or "Space" Button It chooses by default the option "Good".

I want when reviewing, when Pressing "Enter" It doesn't anything.

I want to do that because I'd like to assing "Enter" to anoher action with Autohotkey.

I know this option is available in the preferences of the newest versions (2.1.6+), But The reason that prevents me from using it in the latest versions is, I have some Add ons don’t work on the newest versions (2.1.6+), they work on V 2.1.51 that I use.

Is there any way to disable the shortcut "Enter" in the review window after showing the answer in V 2.1.51?

Any help to do so Please!